# Version incompatibility node and npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I using from this command "nvm install node" and then `nvm use 11`, but get me bellow error:

```
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=14.15.0 <15"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.7.0","node":"11.15.0"}
```

But I need just to use `nvm use 11`, what can I do? (witch version of npm?)

My system is Mac.

My error is:

```
> npm install && npx cordova prepare && npx gulp

npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev: wanted: {"node":">=14.15.0 <15"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.7.0"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=14.15.0 <15"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.7.0","node":"11.15.0"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/asheq/.npm/_logs/2021-09-02T04_50_08_043Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev setup: `npm install && npx cordova prepare && npx gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev setup script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/asheq/.npm/_logs/2021-09-02T04_50_08_060Z-debug.log
```

Comment: When do you get this error? While running another command or while running `nvm use 11`?

Comment: @Akhil, I edited my question, you can see. thank's

Comment: `Unsupported engine for moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev`. You have to use an older version of moodlemobile which supports node 11 I guess.

Comment: Or if you are not limited by the node version, you could use node version 14 by running `nvm install 14 && nvm use 14` and try again.

Comment: @Akhil, I am use from this document https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Updating_plugins it say you should use from nvm use 11.

Comment: @Akhil, nvm use 11 # This is important, npm commands will not work in other versions...

Comment: Are you following some kind of tutorial? If so can you point me to that? If node 11 is important you would have to find a version of moodlemobile that supports node 11 or less. The current version's package.json explicitly  marks `"engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.0 <15"
  }`

Comment: Just install the version you need you use.

Comment: Your error is not from `nvm use 11`, it is from  `npm install && npx cordova prepare && npx gulp`. Your npm command require you to use node version ">=14.15.0 <15". It would not work if you use node version 11.

Comment: @RickyMo, But in document say nvm use 11 # This is important, npm commands will not work in other versions, what can I do?

Comment: In what document?

Comment: @RickyMo, It is here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Updating_plugins

Comment: That document was written for moodle 2, while you are installing moodle 3.9.6.  Just install whatever node version npm tell you to install. Give it a try instead of strictly following a dated document.

Comment: @RickyMo, Ok, Thank's a lot.

Comment: @RickyMo, get me npm ERR! Failed at the moodlemobile@3.9.6-dev prod:android script.

Comment: @RickyMo, thank's for your guide, my problem resolved with your guide and all of things good work. Insert you answer for accept.